# Modified Bessel function

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions

I use the standard notations. When $x$ is real then by definition
$$
I_{\nu}(x)=e^{-\nu\pi i/2}J_{\nu}(ix).
$$
I want to define $I_{\nu}$ for complex $z$. Watson (Treatise of the Theory of Bessel Functions, 2nd ed, 3.7, p.77) says it is
$$
\begin{cases}
I_{\nu}(z)=e^{-\nu\pi i/2}J_{\nu}\left(ze^{\pi i/2}\right), & (-\pi<\arg z\leq\pi/2),\\
I_{\nu}(z)=e^{(3/2)\nu\pi i}J_{\nu}\left(ze^{-(3/2)\pi i}\right), & (\pi/2<\arg z\leq\pi).
\end{cases}
$$

**Q1**. $e^{\pi i/2}\neq e^{-(3/2)\pi i}$?

**Q2**. Why not good to simply put $z$ in place of $x$?

**Q3**. How was chosen these two cases of argument of $z$? What is the reason?

Watson says "it is usually convenient", but I want mathematical justification.

Comment: Should the different cases have different argument ranges?  They both have $-\pi < \arg z \leq \pi/2$ now.

Comment: @AntonioVargas thanks, it was a typo, I corrected it.